# telegraf.js bot does not respond in group

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I use very basic Telegram bot. The response are working very well when directly message to bot. At the same time the bot only respond for commands in the group.

**Is there any option to work all the bot features with in group ?**

```
const config = require('./config.json')
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf(config.token);


bot.start((ctx) => ctx.reply('Welcome'))
bot.help((ctx) => ctx.reply('Send me a sticker'))
bot.on('sticker', (ctx) => ctx.reply(''))
bot.hears('hi', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hey there'))
bot.hears(/buy/i, (ctx) => ctx.reply('Buy-buy'))

bot.command('oldschool', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Hello'))
bot.command('modern', ({ reply }) => reply('Yo'))
bot.command('hipster', Telegraf.reply('λ'))


bot.startPolling()
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, bots in Telegram group chats are placed into [privacy mode](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) -- they will only receive callbacks for messages which contain /commands or which are replies to the bot's own message. (They will also receive callbacks for service messages, like when users join or leave the group.)

A group admin will need to disable privacy mode for the bot to receive all messages in the group.

Comment: Is it possible to know the group privacy mode one for the bot with condition ?